# @media in child theme wordpress, is not at all responding and completly ignoriong the css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[image]
I need to improve my webpage design, when shown on smartphone.I am working in wordpress and making alterations through the childtheme. I am using a media query. Right now the @media is set to min-width 600px.

However NOTHING is happening. No matter how i tweek the code or what setting/classes/div's I am using, nothing changes when I go to see the page on a smartphone. The closest I got was modifying a .h3 tag, but then alterations appeared in screen mode - not in smartphone mode.

Even weider this code was working fine a couple of days ago, and .Profilbillede was repositioned using this media query.

Is there any way that the media query cannot be "linked" correctly, in the child theme? I've tried to look for syntax errors, but I cannot find any.

Specifically I need to add padding to h2#lfb_mainFormTitle. Right after this

...

needs to be positioned lower and then follows 
 which need to be positioned below the

...

. Am i making any sense?

This is the first time I am doing this

--------------------------CSS here--------------------------

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) {

    /*billede nederst til højre*/
    .Profilbillede {transform: translateY(-46px;)
}

    h2#lfb_mainFormTitle {
    font-size:32px!important;
    background-color: blue;

}

}
```

[image]

Comment: please read tag description before using them

Comment: @TemaniAfif how does these tag descriptions not apply to my question?

Comment: If you view the page in Chrome using Dev Tools, resize your browser to <600px; do you see your CSS in the panel; whether it is crossed out or not?

Comment: simply read the description and you will understand

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 I just added a screenshot - i realize the value is not 600 px, but 375, and i resized the screen accrodingly

Comment: You've written your CSS correctly then, it's just being overwritten by something else in your code. Have a look at [specificity in css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for how you can resolve this; alternatively the `!important` tag will also work, however it's not recommended going forward.

Comment: Could I show you some remaining code, where these alterations needs to be applied?

Comment: It is wierd to think that something else has overwritten the code, because I have not opened the file since the last time I worked on it, where it worked

Comment: I added a screenshot of the remaining code

Comment: It could be a cache issue then if it was working last time. Try pressing CTRL+F5 whilst viewing it in the Chrome Dev Tools again and see if that will fix it.

Comment: i already tried to clean my cach several times. I would truly appreciate If I could show you the remaing code? i attached it in a screenshot